# Circular LinkList Compatriot Game in Javascript

Tags: javascript, linked-list, circular-list

I found this question in O'Reilly Data Structure and Algorithm in Javascript "According to legend, the first-century Jewish historian Flavius Josephus was about
to be captured along with a band of 40 compatriots by Roman soldiers during the
Jewish-Roman War. The Jewish soldiers decided that they preferred suicide to being
captured and devised a plan for their demise. They were to form a circle and kill
every third soldier until they were all dead. Josephus and one other decided they
wanted no part of this and quickly calculated where they needed to place themselves
so they would be the last survivors. Write a program that allows you to place n
people in a circle and specify that every mth person will be killed. The program
should determine the number of the last two people left in the circle. Use a circularly
linked list to solve the problem."

this is my solution

```
function Node(element) {
    this.element = element;
    this.next = null;
}

function LList() {
    this.head = new Node("head");
    this.head.next = this.head;
    this.find = find;
    this.insert = insert;
    this.display = display;
    this.findPrevious = findPrevious;
    this.remove = remove;
    this.advance = advance;
    this.count = count;
}

function remove(item) {
    var prevNode = this.findPrevious(item);
    if (!(prevNode.next == this.head)) {
        prevNode.next = prevNode.next.next;
    }
}
function findPrevious(item) {
    var currNode = this.head;
    while (!(currNode.next == this.head) &&
        (currNode.next.element != item)) {
        currNode = currNode.next;
    }
    return currNode;
}
function display() {
    var currNode = this.head;
    while (!(currNode.next == this.head)) {
        print(currNode.next.element);
        currNode = currNode.next;
    }
}
function count() {
    var currNode = this.head;
    var count = 0;
    while (!(currNode.next == this.head)) {
        count++
        currNode = currNode.next;
    }
    return count;
}
function find(item) {
    var currNode = this.head;
    while (currNode.element != item) {
        currNode = currNode.next;
    }
    return currNode;
}
function insert(newElement, item) {
    var newNode = new Node(newElement);
    var current = this.find(item);
    newNode.next = current.next;
    current.next = newNode;
}

function advance(item, n) {
    var currNode = this.find(item);
    for (let i = n; i > 0; i--) {
        currNode = currNode.next;
    }
    return currNode;
}



function survivor(number, position) {
    //40 compatriots
    //kill every third soldier. advance by 3
    //last two survivors

    //place n people in a circle
    var compatroits = new LList();
    var currNode = compatroits.head;

    for (let i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
        compatroits.insert(i, currNode.element);
        currNode = currNode.next;
    }

    //kill every mth person in the circle
    //start from head
    var currItem = compatroits.head.element;
    while (compatroits.count() > 2) {
        //advance mth person
        var killNode = compatroits.advance(currItem, position);

        //set new start point to m.next node
        currItem = killNode.next.element;

        //remove mth person
        compatroits.remove(killNode.element);
    }


    //determine the last two people in the circle
    return compatroits.display();
}
```

Does anyone a more efficient way to sole the problem?

Comment: There are of course ways to be more efficient -- especially if you're willing to make doubly linked list. That might be a good question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com. But as it is, there are some problems with the actual output. For example when I run `survivor(40, 3)` it looks like it actually makes a list of 41 -- 40 plus the head. Then it delete every 4th man.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your feedback. I think it appears to delete the 4th man because it restart the count whenever one node is deleted. so the deleted node is not counted as one, instead, the next node after the deleted node is counted as one. and yes it does create 40 elements plus the head. I do think I can make adjustments to get rid of those two bugs. I will also but it up on codereview. Thanks again for your feedback